# Installing XML::DOM module fails

Tags: perl, cpan, activeperl

I couldn't find any solution for two weeks.!!!!
I try to install CPAN Modules using the cpan.exe.

When I try to install a module with "install XML::DOM" fails stating dmake.exe is NOT OK,

here is my error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ehsan\Documents>cpan
Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 5932).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile 'C:\Perl\cpan\.lock'
Y/n) [y] y

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan> install XML::DOM
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 24 Oct 2013 11:09:28 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::DOM'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-DOM-1.44.tar.g
k
Scanning cache C:\Perl/cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................D

XML-DOM-1.44/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DocumentType.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DocumentFragment.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/AttlistDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Notation.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Attr.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/ProcessingInstruction.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Entity.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Document.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Parser.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NodeList.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Node.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/ElementDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/EntityReference.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NodeList.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/CharacterData.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DOMException.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/PerlSAX.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NamedNodeMap.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NamedNodeMap.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Comment.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Element.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/XMLDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/CDATASection.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DOMImplementation.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Text.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/AttDef.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/Handler/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/Handler/BuildDOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/t/
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_minus.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_noexpand.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_template.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_cdata.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_modify.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_text.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_cdata.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_attr.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_minus.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_attr.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_encode.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_example.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.ent
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_print.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_documenttype.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.dtd
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_astress.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/build_dom.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_print.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_astress.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_modify.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_example.t
XML-DOM-1.44/FAQ.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/Changes
XML-DOM-1.44/MANIFEST
XML-DOM-1.44/META.yml
XML-DOM-1.44/CmpDOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/minutes.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/REC-xml-19980210.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/BUGS
XML-DOM-1.44/CheckAncestors.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/XML-Parser-2.31.patch
XML-DOM-1.44/Makefile.PL
XML-DOM-1.44/README

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite XML::Parser::PerlSAX 0.07 not found.
Warning: prerequisite XML::RegExp 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for XML-DOM
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz       ----
    XML::Parser::PerlSAX [requires]
    XML::RegExp [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX'
Running make for K/KM/KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\K\KM\KMACLEOD\libxml-perl-0.08.t
gz ok
libxml-perl-0.08/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/Subs.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/CanonXMLWriter.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/Sample.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/XMLWriter.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/ActionTempl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/PatternTempl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/Amsterdam.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/MatchName.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/ToObjects.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/SAX2Perl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Perl2SAX.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/ESISParser.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Parser/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Parser/PerlSAX.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/Parent.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/Visitor.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/CreatingPatActModules.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/interface-style.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/modules.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/sax-2.0-adv.html
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/UsingPatActModules.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/PerlSAX.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/mirror.sh
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/sax-2.0.html
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/UsingPerlSAX.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/index.html
libxml-perl-0.08/Changes
libxml-perl-0.08/MANIFEST
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/schema.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/MyHandler.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/myhandler.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/myhandler.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/schema.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/perlsax-test.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/esis-test.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/t/
libxml-perl-0.08/t/schema.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/stream.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/xp_sax.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/subs.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/canon_xml_writer.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/amsterdam.t
libxml-perl-0.08/ChangeLog
libxml-perl-0.08/libxml-perl.spec
libxml-perl-0.08/libxml-perl-0.08.spec
libxml-perl-0.08/Makefile.PL
libxml-perl-0.08/README

  CPAN.pm: Building K/KM/KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for libxml-perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib': No such
e or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\.exists'
  KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'XML::RegExp'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-RegExp-0.04.ta
z ok
XML-RegExp-0.04/
XML-RegExp-0.04/META.yml
XML-RegExp-0.04/test.pl
XML-RegExp-0.04/README
XML-RegExp-0.04/Changes
XML-RegExp-0.04/MANIFEST
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/XML/
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/XML/RegExp.pm
XML-RegExp-0.04/Makefile.PL

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::RegExp
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib\XML': No s
 file or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\XML\.exists'
  TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\XML-DOM-1.44-P
El

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX => 0.07' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.
tar.gz' failed when processing 'KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz' with 'make
NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::RegExp => 0' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz' f
ed when processing 'TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Conti
ng, but chances to succeed are limited.
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib': No such
e or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\.exists'
  TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz             : make NO
 TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz                 : make NO
 TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz              : make NO
```

i asked this question in Perlmonks and i got this answer :
"Looks like you are (or have been) using MKS, which can confuse things such as which shell dmake invokes and so on. I suggest you remove it (the path to MKS) from your system PATH variable (example). Once you've done this start a new command prompt and retry the installation"

what should i do?

Comment: The suggestion from perlmonks sounds reasonable. Did you try it?

Comment: I want to try that but i don't know what should i do ?i am really beginner in Perl.

Comment: Removing something from the PATH environment variable is not a Perl question, but a Windows question. There's somewhere a dialog where you can adjust environment variables. Alternatively you can set the PATH in the command prompt. But don't ask for details, I am not a Windows expert.

Comment: my problem is which value should i set!!!!

Comment: Are you familiar with environment variables in Windows?

Comment: No.i don't know what is that!!!

Comment: Other question: can you install the module using ActivePerl's ppm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem here:

```
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib': No such
e or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\.exists'
  TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
```

Your `dmake` call comes from a Strawberry Perl installation, and it invokes what looks like ActivePerl. Down that `PATH` lies madness. If you want to use CPAN with Strawberry Perl, then remove the ActivePerl directories from your `PATH`.

---

Specifically, try this:

```
set PATH C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin;C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin
cpan XML::DOM
```

Comment: I found that mixing ActivePerl and StrawberryPerl is not problematic. Quite opposite, the ActivePerl system may detect gcc & dmake provided by StrawberryPerl and make compilation of XS modules possible. It's probably MKS (whatever this is) which is causing the problems.

Comment: @mob:I changed that and now i get this Error:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617905/install-xmldom-module-error

Comment: @ Slaven Rezic:so what should i do?

Comment: @SlavenRezic Well it depends what the target is. If you want to install a module to use with Strawberry Perl, then you don't want the ActivePerl programs to appear first in the path.

Comment: OP tagged this question with "activeperl", so probably that's his target.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is probably here:

```
Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX => 0.07' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.
tar.gz' failed when processing 'KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz' with 'make
NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::RegExp => 0' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz' f
ed when processing 'TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Conti
ng, but chances to succeed are limited.
```

You need to have XML::Parser::PerlSAX and XML::RegExp installed first.

Comment: Check the whole log. CPAN.pm tried to install these modules, but failed.