# install XML::DOM module Error

Tags: xml, perl, cpanel

i'm having loads of problem in trying to install CPAN Modules. Using the cpan.exe, I try to install a module with, for example, "install XML::DOM" but I end up hitting a wall. when the install finishes it says dmake.exe is NOT OK
here is my error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ehsan\Documents>cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.00)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan> install XML::DOM
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Catching error: "Transfer truncated: only 928279 out of 1467140 bytes received\c
J" at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/CPAN.pm line 392, <IN> line 1.
        CPAN::shell() called at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/App/Cpan.pm line 338
        App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at C:/strawberry/perl/li
b/App/Cpan.pm line 421
        App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin/cpan.bat line
 25
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Caught SIGINT, trying to continue
Got another SIGINTLockfile removed.
Transfer truncated: only 135499 out of 1467140 bytes received
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? ^
C
C:\Users\ehsan\Documents>cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.00)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan> install XML::DOM
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Creating database file ...
Done!
Running install for module 'XML::DOM'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/T/TJ/TJMATHER/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-DOM-1.44.ta
r.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite XML::Parser::PerlSAX 0.07 not found.
Warning: prerequisite XML::RegExp 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for XML-DOM
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz       ----
    XML::RegExp [requires]
    XML::Parser::PerlSAX [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'XML::RegExp'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-RegExp-0.04
.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::RegExp
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.exe
 -c C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib\XML'
: No such file or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\XML\.exists'
  TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'XML::RegExp'.
Failed during this command:
 TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz              : make NO
```

Comment: A download failed. So try it again.

Comment: @mob There was a 2nd download attempt which was successful. And then again the error while executing `...\mksnt\sh.exe`, the same error as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609897/installing-xmldom-module-fails/19614633

Comment: What's the output if you type "set shell" in the command prompt?

Comment: I got this output:SHELL=C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.exe

Comment: I checked this path but i didn't find the sh.exe file